Generating two points between two existing points using PyQGIS
I have the following problem: I have two points and I need a script to create two new points that are contained between the existing points and that the 4 points are collinear. I will add two images to present the problem.

The first image is the two starting points, points 1 and 2.



The second image represents how I need it to look, creating points 3
and 4 between points 1 and 2.



I would like the distances between points (1 and 3) and (2 and 4) to
be 1/4 of the distance between points (1 and 2).


Construct a linestring geometry using your existing points, then interpolate()

Here is an example of how to achieve that with Pyqgis. This code can run in QGIS python console within a project with an empty point layer called "test".
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('test')[0]
points = [QgsPointXY(100,100), QgsPointXY(0,0)]
line = QgsLineString(points)

new_points = (line.interpolatePoint(line.length()/4), line.interpolatePoint(line.length()/4 * 3), ) 
with edit(layer):
    for point in new_points:
        feat = QgsFeature()
        feat.setGeometry(point)
        layer.addFeature(feat)


My solution is a bit long and is based on geometry and geodesy. In my example, the solution calculates the azimuth and distance between two predefined points in the Amersfoort / RD New coordinate system (EPSG:28992) and uses these values to estimate the coordinates of two new points (point 3 and point 4). The new points are added to a memory-based QGIS vector layer and displayed on the map (see below).
import numpy as np
from qgis.core import (
    QgsVectorLayer,
    QgsField,
    QgsPointXY,
    QgsFeature,
    QgsGeometry,
    QgsProject
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

# Function to calculate angle in grads
def a_grad_comp(Dx, Dy):
    a_rad = np.arctan(Dx / Dy)
    a_grad = a_rad * 200 / np.pi
    return a_grad

# Function to calculate azimuth in grads
def azimuth(x0, y0, x1, y1):
    dx = x1 - x0
    dy = y1 - y0

    if dx == 0 and dy == 0:
        print('Error: The points are identical.')
        return None
    
    if dy == 0:
        return 100 if dx > 0 else 300
    
    if dx == 0:
        return 0 if dy > 0 else 200

    if dx > 0 and dy > 0:
        return a_grad_comp(dx, dy)
    elif dx > 0 and dy < 0:
        return a_grad_comp(dx, dy) + 200
    elif dx < 0 and dy < 0:
        return a_grad_comp(dx, dy) + 200
    elif dx < 0 and dy > 0:
        return a_grad_comp(dx, dy) + 400

    return None  # This line is technically unreachable due to the elif structure

# Function to estimate new coordinates
def estimating_coords(x0, y0, Dist, azim):
    x1 = x0 + Dist * np.sin(azim * np.pi / 200)
    y1 = y0 + Dist * np.cos(azim * np.pi / 200)
    return x1, y1

# Create a new memory layer
layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=EPSG:28992", "My Points Layer", "memory")

# Add fields to the layer
layer_provider = layer.dataProvider()
layer_provider.addAttributes([QgsField("id", QVariant.Int), QgsField("name", QVariant.String)])
layer.updateFields()

# Define the initial points - Projected CRS (EPSG:28992) - Netherlands 
points = [
    QgsPointXY(135000, 400000),  # Point 1
    QgsPointXY(155000, 463000)   # Point 2
]

# Add initial points to the layer
for i, point in enumerate(points):
    feature = QgsFeature()
    feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(point))
    feature.setAttributes([i+1, f"Point {i+1}"])
    layer_provider.addFeature(feature)

# Extract coordinates from the first two points
x0, y0 = points[0].x(), points[0].y()
x1, y1 = points[1].x(), points[1].y()

# Calculate azimuth and distance between the first two points
az01 = azimuth(x0, y0, x1, y1)
dist_01 = np.sqrt((x1 - x0)**2 + (y1 - y0)**2)

# Estimate new coordinates 
point_3_coords = estimating_coords(x0, y0, dist_01 / 4, az01)
point_4_coords = estimating_coords(x0, y0, dist_01 *3/4, az01)

# Add the new points to the layer
new_points = [point_3_coords, point_4_coords]

for i, coords in enumerate(new_points, start=3):  # start=3 to continue the IDs
    feature = QgsFeature()
    feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(coords[0], coords[1])))
    feature.setAttributes([i, f"Point {i}"])
    layer_provider.addFeature(feature)

# Update the layer and add it to the map
layer.updateExtents()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)



Actually this longer procedure gives the very same result as the shorter one by @YoLecomte for EPSG:28992.
